# Trying to control a backgroundcolor from a label when I add it to a list

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to control the backgroundcolor by this code below but the color does not turn black as I want it to.

I load my public color in my list as transparent and when It finds that I want to make it black but it does not seem to work. Any clues where I go wrong?

XAML:

```
<Label BackgroundColor="{Binding thebackgroundColor}" />
```

CODE:

```
public class pubClass 
{

public Color thebackgroundColor { get; set; }

}

async void loadOurItem () 
{
ourList.Add (new pubClass () 
                { 
                    thebackgroundColor = Color.Transparent

                });
}


protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
            loadOurItem ();
            var theClass = new pubClass ();
            if (theClass.thebackgroundColor != null) {

                theClass.thebackgroundColor = Color.Black;
            }

        }
    }
```

UPDATED:

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged(theClass.thebackgroundColor)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(theClass.thebackgroundColor = Color.Black));
    }
}
```

Comment: pubClass needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Check my updated code, something like that? And remove it from OnAppearing?

Comment: There is more to it than that.  See https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/.  Also, the code you posted doesn't show where you setup the BindingContext for your page.  And finally, you seem to be posting snippets from multiple files, which makes your code hard to read.  Please clearly indicate where each piece of the code comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are wanting to update your `ListView` item from adjusting your model although your getting stuck along the way and a little confused?

Try the following example below that is a simple example that creates an `ObservableCollection` of your `MyPubClass`.

The button at the bottom of the screen will show how you can update the model directly by modifying each item, and having those changes reflected on the `ListView`.

In this example each item just cycles through the colors `Red`, `Green` and `Blue`.

In the `MyViewCell` class, this is what you will most likely be creating something similar to in `XAML`, with binding to the `Labels`'s `BackgroundColor` property through your model's `TheBackgroundColor` property that implements a `BindableProperty`.

**Example:-**

```
StackLayout objStackLayout = new StackLayout()
{
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
};

ListView objListView = new ListView();
objStackLayout.Children.Add(objListView);

objListView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(MyViewCell));

ObservableCollection<MyPubClass> objItems = new ObservableCollection<MyPubClass>();
objListView.ItemsSource = objItems;

objItems.Add(new MyPubClass(Color.Red));
objItems.Add(new MyPubClass(Color.Green));
objItems.Add(new MyPubClass(Color.Blue));

Button objButton1 = new Button()
{
    Text = "Change Colors"
};
objButton1.Clicked+=((o2,e2)=>
{
    foreach (MyPubClass objItem in objItems)
    {
        if (objItem.TheBackgroundColor == Color.Red)
        {
            objItem.TheBackgroundColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else if (objItem.TheBackgroundColor == Color.Green)
        {
            objItem.TheBackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
        }
        else if (objItem.TheBackgroundColor == Color.Blue)
        {
            objItem.TheBackgroundColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
});
objStackLayout.Children.Add(objButton1);
```

**Custom ViewCell:-**

```
public class MyViewCell
    : ViewCell
{
    public MyViewCell()
    {
        Label objLabel = new Label();
        objLabel.Text = "Hello";

        objLabel.SetBinding(Label.BackgroundColorProperty, "TheBackgroundColor");

        this.View  = objLabel;
    }
}
```

**Supporting Class:-**

```
public class MyPubClass
    : Xamarin.Forms.View
{


    public static readonly BindableProperty TheBackgroundColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create<MyPubClass, Color>(p => p.TheBackgroundColor, default(Color));

    public Color TheBackgroundColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(TheBackgroundColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TheBackgroundColorProperty, value); }
    }


    public MyPubClass(Color pobjColor)
    {
        this.TheBackgroundColor = pobjColor;
    }

}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but this will definitly help me out. Thx!